# English Auction rejected translations are not shown

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

I have made a sample scenario:

1. Start auction with a deadline of +10 slots
2. wait for 12 slots
3. Bid
4. Wait for 1 slot to allow TX to be processed

The third transaction is not shown - which is understandable since the transaction should not be happening.

My question is: how can I figure out what was wrong, and why did the TX was not made.
There is no error log in the log/trace.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do this in repl before simulation?

```
import Data.Default
import Ledger.TimeSlot
slotToEndPOSIXTime def 10
```

The last command will give you the correct value  for spDeadline after 10 slots.

Comment: What exatly the cabal repl does?

Comment: Yes I have. I put in the correct timeslot, and deliberately went over the deadline. The TX did not go through, but I could find any reference (log/trace) to the reason the TX failed

Comment: What about waiting for 2 slots at the end?